# Query data from database with condition

Tags: android, sqlite

this is my language table

```
/*
         * initialValues in Languages( 
         * KEY_LANG_ID, 
         * KEY_LANG, \\ language name
         * KEY_ACT) \\ 0= not active, 1= active
         */
        ContentValues initialValues3 = new ContentValues();
        initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "English");
        initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "1");
        db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
        initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "German");
        initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "1");
        db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
        initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "Spain");
        initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "0");
        db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
        initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "Italy");
        initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "0");
        db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
        initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "China");
        initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "0");
        db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
```

this is my sentences table

```
/*initialValues in Sentences(
 * KEY_SEN_ID,
 * KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN,
 * KEY_SEN_ID_LANG,
 * KEY_SEN,
 * KEY_SEN_READING,
 * KEY_ACT_VOL)
* */
```

I want to show sentences in my list view and sentence must check KEY_ACT from language table if KEY_ACT =1 then sentence show from above in list view must only have English and German sentence so I try to query like this

```
public Cursor getSen_List(long id_thsen ) {
    String strTmp = "select "
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_LANG+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_READING+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_ACT_VOL+","
        +LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG
        +" from "+SENS_TABLE+ ","+LANGS_TABLE
        +" where "+SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN + "=" + id_thsen+ " and " 
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG_ID+"=(select "
                                    +LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG_ID
                                    +" from "+LANGS_TABLE
                                    +" where "+LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_ACT+"=1)";
        return db.rawQuery(strTmp,null);
 }
```

but the result is show only same English sentence for 5 time

Does anybody have any idea?

please help.....

Answer (score 0):

I've not used `ContentValues` before, but it looks like since you are reusing the same object over and over again, you keep re-inserting the same values:

```
ContentValues initialValues3 = new ContentValues();
initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "English");
initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "1");
db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
/* ok so far, initialValues3 now contains the "English" entry */
initialValues3.put(KEY_LANG, "German");
initialValues3.put(KEY_ACT, "1");
/* initialValues3 now has both the "English" entry and the "German" one */
db.insert(LANGS_TABLE, null, initialValues3);
/* the "English" entry has now been added twice, and the "German" one once */
...etc
```

I think you might want to call `initialValues3.clear()` after each insert.

As for the rest of the query, you are using a column `KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN` that you have not provided us any details for.

Comment: I've edit table already. By the way I conform to your suggest but it still happen 5 time what should I do..

Comment: @praew_z In your `and` clause you have `and "+SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG_ID+`, but `KEY_LANG_ID` is not a column on `SENS_TABLE`.  I suspect you might also want `"in(select "` rather than `=`.